# Can not install xrdp using apt-get on debian 8.5 (tinkeboard os) (Arm)

Tags: debian, arm

I just got a tinkerboard to make into a cheap server, I am trying to install xrdp. Here is what have tried so far

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo apt-get -f install xrdp
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-update
sudo apt-get install clear

$ sudo apt-get install xrdp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xrdp is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm3.5 zlib1g-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up xrdp (0.9.1-4~bpo8+1) ...

Generating 2048 bit rsa key...

ssl_gen_key_xrdp1 ok

saving to /etc/xrdp/rsakeys.ini

A dependency job for xrdp.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript xrdp, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package xrdp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xrdp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output of journalctl -xe is

```
Mar 27 22:14:25 linaro-alip xrdp-sesman[3140]: (3140)(-1225464928)[CORE ] shutti
Mar 27 22:14:25 linaro-alip systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp session manager.
-- Subject: Unit xrdp-sesman.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit xrdp-sesman.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 27 22:14:25 linaro-alip systemd[1]: Dependency failed for xrdp daemon.
-- Subject: Unit xrdp.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit xrdp.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.

Mar 27 22:14:25 linaro-alip systemd[1]: xrdp-sesman.service: Failed with result     
Mar 27 22:14:29 linaro-alip sudo[3059]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed f    
Mar 27 22:15:24 linaro-alip kernel: RTL871X: nolinked power save leave    
Mar 27 22:15:26 linaro-alip kernel: RTL871X: nolinked power save enter    
Mar 27 22:16:28 linaro-alip kernel: RTL871X: nolinked power save leave
Mar 27 22:16:29 linaro-alip kernel: RTL871X: nolinked power save enter
```

Comment: The important line is the first one and you pasted the truncated version

Comment: Please edit by addidng the content of your `sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

You should install `xrdp` from the `main` repo because the backported package [(xrdp (0.9.1-4~bpo8+1)](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/xrdp) depends on : `libc6 (>= 2.15) [not arm64]`.

Remove `xrdp` , then edit your `sources.list` and your [`pin-priority`](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) to allow the package to be installed from the stable repo. finally upgrade your package and install `xrdp` as usually.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get intall xrdp
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I followed your instructions the best i could. 
I changed the pin priority to stable / 700
It looked like it installed as it should. 
When I rebooted the computer it did not boot saying root  was locked. I  may have done something wrong.